# Sidekiq middleware not logging to development.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleware, sidekiq

I would like to create a middleware that searches in the queues (typically default) if there are jobs with the same arguments.
Typically I send arguments like this:
perform(client_id, port_number)

I would like to be able to see, using the middleware, if there is already a client_id and a port_number in the default queue, and if there is I just return and I log it into the logger.

This is what I have so far (I want to log the data for now).

in config/initializers/sidekiq.rb I have

```
require 'sidekiq/api'

#Sidekiq default host redis://localhost:6379
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/12' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/12' }
  config.client_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add ArgumentLogging
  end
end
```

Now, "ArgumentLogging" should be the class that will log the arguments; but I don't know where to add the code for the middleware to be honest.

I added it into app/middleware/argument_logging.rb

```
module Sidekiq
    class ArgumentLogging
      # @param [String, Class] worker_class the string or class of the worker class being enqueued
      # @param [Hash] job the full job payload
      #   * @see https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Job-Format
      # @param [String] queue the name of the queue the job was pulled from
      # @param [ConnectionPool] redis_pool the redis pool
      # @return [Hash, FalseClass, nil] if false or nil is returned,
      #   the job is not to be enqueued into redis, otherwise the block's
      #   return value is returned
      # @yield the next middleware in the chain or the enqueuing of the job
      def call(worker_class, job, queue, redis_pool) 
        # return false/nil to stop the job from going to redis
        Rails.logger.info("Reading and logging #{queue} with arguments: #{job.inspect}")
        yield
      end
    end
end
```

This is what I have so far. But I cannot see in my "development.log" file any string similar to "Reading and logging #{queue} with arguments: #{job.inspect}"

Does anyone know how to use Middleware and where should I put the code above?
I read all about https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware and other StackOverflow questions and blogs, but it seems like I cannot understand why my code is not triggering.

Thank you and I look forward to hearing from you.

Rob

Comment: Just an update here, SideKiq version is 3.0.6

Comment: That version is approx 4 years out of date.  All current docs will be irrelevant.

Comment: And it's Sidekiq, not SideKiq. :-)

Comment: Hi @MikePerham, my bad. Sorry, the version is: sidekiq (5.1.3). Would you be able to give me some additional insights on how to create the middleware? Thankyou.

Comment: I might have found the problem, I will keep you posted in case.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: https://drivy.engineering/use-sidekiq-middleware/

Comment: I don't have any more content than the wiki page and that blog post.  I hope you can figure out how things work and solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes, on Friday I was able to start logging events. I will read the blog you sent over today. Thank you.